# Selling my own label-making software for Zebra printers

Tags: licensing

I did a little research on Google about the licensing problem of selling original label-making software for Zebra printers and failed to find anything related to it.

Normally there shouldn't be any problem because, I believe, it's no different from making software to print on any other printers.

And I don't think you have to get any licensing permission to print on, say, Epson's printers.

But because printing on Zebra's label printers involving using their creation - ZPL (Zebra Programming Language), now I'm not so sure about the legality of selling anything which have used their creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be no special license requirements on the use of ZPL, or Zebra printers. As ZPL is simply an interface method for such a printer, anyone who lawfully owns such a printer would have any needed license in any case.

Thus, anyone may create (and sell) a computer program to print any sort of labels on a Zebra printer, using ZPL for the purpose.

A general form, such as a label template, is not normally protected by copyright, so anyone may print labels in any format, original or copied from other labels.

Assuming the program itself is original, that is not copied without permission from a copyrighted source, there should be no problem. And the program could be advertised as begin  compatible with Zebra printers, provided it is made clear that Zebra did not make, approve, or endorse the program, with no trademark issue, as this is a case of nominative use.

Comment: I would think the outcome of the Oracle-Google case would have a huge bearing on this, as its a similar concern (you would be implementing some of the printer APIs structures in order to talk to it for example)